# Android - converting string to long value

Tags: android, android-preferences, string-conversion

I am creating a fairly simple android application which is basically a timer, I am trying to make it so that you can set the timer length in the settings and then using preferences retrieve the value and set it as the timer length. I can retrieve the value from the preferences and simply display it.

But when I try to convert the string value (i.e. 1) to a long value using either Long.parseLong(string) or Long.valueOf(String) and Long.valueOf(Int), I don't receive any errors in the code but when I try and start the application, it force closes and the error log says it is caused by NumberFormatException, Here is the the section of code I am using, also if I remove the line that says Long.ParseLong... everything else works fine.

```
        private long interval =    1000 ;
        private long startTime = 30000;



        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_countdown_timer);

                 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

                 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                 builder.append("\n"+ prefs.getString("timerLength","NULL"));
                 startTime = Long.parseLong(builder.toString());




                 TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showTimer);
                 view.setText(builder.toString());
```

Comment: I think your preference return NULL . So it could not be parsed .

Comment: I don't think it does as I can retrieve the value and display it as a string

Comment: Yeh NumberFormatEception, not what that means though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `'\n'` character. The string should only contain a `long` as a String for it to be successfully parsed.

Comment: Also he should remove the prefs returning null. If it returns null it may again throw exception. Does it not make sense to use a try catch as well.

Answer (score 4):

Pls remove "\n"

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(prefs.getString("timerLength","NULL"));
startTime = Long.parseLong(builder.toString());
```